# how to generate a serverside menu with 3 levels?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to generate the bellow menu dynamically using php and mysql

```
 <ul id="prod_nav" class="clearfix">
 <!-- top -->     <li class="active"><a href="05-Pink-02-Category-List.html"    class="top_link"><span class="down">Clothes</span></a>
 <ul>
              <h1> Men </h1>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Shirt         </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">T-shirt       </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Polo shirt    </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Formal shoes  </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Sport shoes   </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Suit          </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Underwear     </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Socks         </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Pants         </a></li>
   </ul>
            <ul>
              <h1> Women </h1>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Shirt            </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">T-shirt          </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Polo shirt       </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">High heel shoes  </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Sport shoes      </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Wedding clothes  </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Underwear        </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Leather          </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Socks            </a></li>
              <li><a href="ProductsList.php">Pants            </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

but I am not sure which way is the best principals for generating the menu?
should I use while loop and if or Case or for loop?

which way is the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: hi yes, I have tried using if() I am able to generate the main category, but i wasn't sure about the menu with a different sub-categorries that if() is the best way to fetch the datas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please used this:

```
   $gender = array('men','women');
   $productlist = array('shirt'=>'shirt_url.php','t-shirt'=>'t-shirt_url.php','polo shirt'=>'polo_shirt.php');

  foreach($gender as $individual) {
        echo "<h2>{$individual}</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($productlist as $product_key=>$product_url) {
          ?>
                 <li><a href="<?php echo $product_url; ?>"><?php echo $product_key; ?></a></li>
        <?php
    }
echo "</ul>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have an array

```
$a=array('shirt','t-shirt','polo shirt','formal shoes','sport shoes','suit','underwear','socks','pants');
```

and use it like this:

```
<ul>
<h1>MEN</h1>
<?php foreach($a as $val) :?>
<li><a href="ProductsList.php"><?php echo $val; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ;?>
</ul>

<ul>
<h1>womaen</h1>
<?php foreach($a as $val) :?>
<li><a href="ProductsList.php"><?php echo $val; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ;?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$gender = array('men','women');
$productlist = array('shirt','t-shirt','polo shirt','formal shoes','sport shoes','suit','underwear','socks','pants');

foreach($gender as $individual) {
    echo "<h2>{$individual}</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach($productlist as $product) {

            <li><a href="ProductsList.php"><?php echo $product; ?></a></li>
        }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```